# Javascript image editing plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, plugins

Where can I find a Javascript or jQuery image editor plugin where users can click on the image to edit it and the plugin allow them to crop, resize, rotate, flip, etc

Comment: Lionel Messi knows jQuery wow.

Comment: sometimes when i in no mood with football i do coding

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS/jQuery Image Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247712/js-jquery-image-editor)

Answer (score 7):

<strike>[Pixastic](http://pixastic.com/lib/)</strike> (not active anymore) and [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com) would be useful but <strike>the best one is definitely [Aviary](http://aviary.com/web)</strike> (deprecated since December 2018).

Comment: Aviary not available anymore since the beginning of December 2018

Comment: Pixastic takes you to a casino site.