# Edit and destroy image paperclip rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have problem with paperclip gem. I'm using Rails 4. I would like to make possiblity for user, to edit image attachment. For now when I'm editing Speaker, I can only upload new image, no edit existing one.

```
= simple_form_for(@speaker) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :first_name
    = f.input :nickname
    = f.input :last_name
    = f.input :description
  - if @speaker.image.exists?
    = image_tag @speaker.image.url(:medium)
    = f.input :delete_image, as: :fake
    = @speaker.image = nil
    = @speaker.save
  = f.input :image
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

However, I can't create checkbox input with :delete_image, so for now, with every refresh site it destroys image (because of @speaker.save).

Could give me some advice, how to fix it ? Solutions from Rails 3 cant help me.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I would like to add checkbox to make possible to delete existing image. For now I can only upload new.

Comment: then why are you doing in your view. Simply send request to controller  and delete there. and better to provide link like 'delete_image' rather than check-box and  by clicking send request to controller and then delete it.

Comment: BTW if you add new image from browse button then it will update existing one.

Comment: But when somebody will edit Speaker, It will no show that there is existing image, it will be just button to add new.

Comment: but i think you have already shown image if present = image_tag @speaker.image.url(:medium). So if image exists then simply show a link next to image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
def remove_picture      
   speaker = Speaker.where(id: params[:id]).first 
   speaker.image.destroy
   redirect_to request.referer
end
```

in your view create following link -

```
- if @speaker.image.exists?
   = link_to "Remove Image", remove_image_path(@speaker), method: :delete
```

in your routes.rb define routes for same

```
delete'/controller/remove_image/:id' => 'controller#remove_image', as: :remove_image
```

Try above code.

Comment: Wow, you're amazing. It's works ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the user to be able to edit the image like they would in Photoshop, or similar (perhaps more simple) image editing apps?  If so then your best option is to use a javascript plugin, eg one of these jQuery plugins:

http://www.sitepoint.com/image-manipulation/
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/11/picedit-jquery-front-end-image-editor-plugin/

These were got just by googling "jquery image editor plugin".

See also this related question:  [Javascript image editing plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311359/javascript-image-editing-plugin)

You will need to choose which one is the best fit for you based on the types of editing options you want to give your user.

Comment: Well, I meant to edit, to make change image to other, no to edit like in photoshop.